# Projective Geometry: Combinatorially, but not projectively equivalent polytopes

Tags: projective-geometry, discrete-geometry, polytopes

I have a hard time understanding Projective Geometry.

My task is to

> Find two polytopes, that are combinatorially, but not projectively
>   equivalent.

What combinatorially equivalent means is clear to me, however I do not really understand the term "projectively equivalent". Can someone explain it to me?

How do I solve this task? I'd appreciate if someone could give me a hint towards the solution.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projective equivalence means that there exists a projective transformation transforming one into the other.

A projective transformation in $d$-dimensional projective space is uniquely defined by $d+2$ points and their images, both in general position. So you can choose any polytope with more than $d+2$ vertices, and if you move one vertex a bit then they have to be projectively non-equivalent since the unmodified vertices would imply an identity transformation but the polytope is not identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But why can I assume that the first 4 vertices of my polytope are mapped to themselves, which would imply an identity Transformation. Isn't it possible that the Images of my vertices are a permutation of my other vertices? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Doc: You are right, in a sufficiently symmetric polytope a permutation of vertices would be possible. So make the polytope non-symmetric or make sure that you don't move the vertex in a symmetric way. I intend to edit my post later.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a pyramid over an arbitrary rectangular base and cut it with a plane parallel to the base to obtain a frustum. The polytope thus obtained is equivalent to a cube. However, it will not be projectively equivalent to the cube in general. Indeed, the diagonals joining opposite vertices from top and bottom are not concurrent in general ( the opposite top and bottom sides will not be in the same plane, if the bottom quadrilateral has opposite sides non-parallel).

Note: a quadruple of points in space lying in the same plane is not projectively equivalent to a quadruple of points not lying in the same plane.